# Linux ipconfig command

Tags: linux, unix

I am a new user of Linux and have freshly installed RHEL5 operating system on 1 of my system.
I have chosen DHCP during installation.

Now after installation when I tried to run ipconfig command on the shell prompt 
I got this message

bash: iconfig: command not found

I am a root user.

I do not understand why am I getting this error. May u please tell me what can be the possible problem and how can I solve it.

Is there any other command to check my current ip .

Comment: This question might be more appropriate on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux) or [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux).

Answer (score 3):

try

```
ifconfig
```

instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
ip addr show
```

or

```
ifconfig
```

or

```
hostname -I
```